# Verbs preceding "information" that mean taking the "information" into account

Tags: word-choice

I have always been using the verb "incorporate" to mean taking some information into account and really got tired of it. I would be grateful if you could kindly suggest some (single) verbs which can substitute "incorporate" in the following example:

> We also **incorporate** information of the US market to make the model more considerate.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus? Can you explain why the thesaurus or dictionary were not helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Incorporate*" doesn't really mean the same as "take into account" anyway; it means to *include* something, so I would say this is only appropriate if the raw information on the US market is actually *included* in the "model" you are speaking about.

There is a marked difference between data *reporting* and data *analysis*.

For example, if I was sent a report and was told that "current market information is *incorporated* in this report" I would expect one of the pages to include that information.

If on the other hand I was told a report "*took into consideration* current market information" I would take that to mean the author had *looked at* that information, *analysed it*, and that his findings had *influenced* the report.

If you really meant *incorporated* then the simple answer is to go for any synonyms such as:

- We also **include** information on the US market to make the model more considerate.
- Our model also **features** information on the US market to make it more considerate.

But if you *do* mean that your model/report is *based on* market information, or that you have *analysed* such information (but not necessarily included that raw data) then perhaps you could say:

- We have also **analysed** current US market information to make the model more considerate.
- Our model also **considers** current US market information to make it more considerate (*although you may need another word instead of "considerate" if you went with this!*)
- We also **thoroughly examine** information from the US market to make the model more considerate.

Hope these help.

*PS I have used the British English spelling of "analyse"; if you are in the US it is of course "analyze".*

*PPS I'm not sure about your terminology, but I don't think "information **of** the US Market" is correct, so I haven't used that in any of my examples. I think perhaps it should be "on" or "from".*

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clear explanation! I think what I really mean is, as you suggest, "include" (or "feature") :-)